# Why does Django require change permission to add a foreign key?

Tags: django

I have two models in my application, Product and Holder. A Holder can have *n* products, and a Product must have one Holder.
These are the classes:

```
class Product:
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Title'), max_length=100)
    holder = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=_('Main Holder'), to=Holder, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...

class Holder:
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...
```

When a user that is a `staff_member` tries to create or change a Product, that specific user **has** to have the database's `change_holder` permission assigned to them, otherwise they can't assign a Holder to that Product. The list of holders won't even load up on the respective field on Admin, [as the following image illustrates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bLtr.png).

Anyway, what I'd like to know is what justifies this behavior. Why would a user need permission to change the foreign key model, if they're not changing that model, but the one that contains the key?